# Mathematica running out of memory when fitting parameters of system of differential equations

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, wolfram-mathematica, cache-control

I encountered a memory problem in Mathematica when I tried to process my experimental data. I'm using Mathematica to find the optimal parameters for a system of three partial differential equations.

When the `e` parameter was greater than 0.4, Mathematica consumed a lot of memory. For `e < 0.4`, the program worked properly.

I have tried using `$HistoryLength = 0`, and reducing  `AccuracyGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` with no success.

I'm trying to understand what mistakes I made, and how I may limit the memory usage.

```
Clear[T, L, e, v, q, C0, R, data, model];
T = 13200; 
L = 0.085; 
e = 0.41; 
v = 0.000557197; 
q = 0.1618; 
C0 = 0.0256; 
R = 0.00075;

data = {{L, 600, 0.141124587}, {L, 1200, 0.254134509}, {L, 1800, 
    0.342888644}, {L, 2400, 0.424476295}, {L, 3600, 0.562844542}, {L, 
    4800, 0.657111356}, {L, 6000, 0.75137817}, 
       {L, 7200, 0.815876516}, {L, 8430, 0.879823594}, {L, 9000, 
    0.900771775}, {L, 13200, 1}};

model[(De_)?NumberQ, (Kf_)?NumberQ, (Y_)?NumberQ] := 
 model[De, Kf, Y] =  yeld /. Last[Last[
     NDSolve[{
       v D[Ci[z, t], z] + D[Ci[z, t], t] == -((
         3 (1 - e) Kf (Ci[z, t] - C0))/(
         R e (1 - (R Kf (1 - R/r[z, t]))/De))),
       D[r[z, t], t] == (R^2 Kf (Ci[z, t] - C0))/(
        q r[z, t]^2 (1 - (R Kf (1 - R/r[z, t]))/De)),
       D[yeld[z, t], t] == Y*(v e Ci[z, t])/(L q (1 - e)),
       r[z, 0] == R,
       Ci[z, 0] == 0,
       Ci[0, t] == 0,
       yeld[z, 0] == 0},
      {r[z, t], Ci[z, t], yeld}, {z, 0, L}, {t, 0, T}]]]

fit = FindFit[
  data, {model[De, Kf, Y][z, t], {0.97  < Y < 1.03, 
    10^-6 < Kf < 10^-4, 10^-13 < De < 10^-9}}, 
     {{De, 10^-12}, {Kf,  10^-6}, {Y, 1}}, {z, t}, Method -> NMinimize]

data = {{600, 0.141124587}, {1200, 0.254134509}, {1800, 
    0.342888644}, {2400, 0.424476295}, {3600, 0.562844542}, {4800, 
    0.657111356}, {6000, 0.75137817}, {7200, 0.815876516}, 
       {8430, 0.879823594}, {9000, 0.900771775}, {13200, 1}}; 

YYY = model[De /. fit[[1]], Kf /. fit[[2]], Y /. fit[[3]]]; 

Show[Plot[Evaluate[YYY[L, t]], {t, 0, T}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]
```

Link to the .nb file: http://www.4shared.com/folder/249TSjlz/_online.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please clean up the spelling, grammar, and punctuation in the text of your question to the best of your ability.  Thank you.  (Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8311625/edit) link below your question.)

Comment: What do you mean by expressions like `(Subscript[C, i]^(1,0))[z,t]` in `model`? Was that supposed to be `Derivative[1,0][Subscript[C, i]][z,t]`?

Comment: Also, I cannot download your Notebook file.  The site appears to be trying to install something on my machine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I formatted the code and corrected the grammar for the OP, so it should be more readable.

Comment: @Heike, that is probably what the OP meant. In the `OutputForm`, that is what appears to be written for `Derivative[1,0][f][z,t]`. I'll fix it.

Comment: user1058051, by `(Ci^(0,1))[z,t]` did you mean the first derivative of `Ci[z,t]` with respect to `t`, and similarly for `(Ci^(1,0))[z,t]`? If so, why did you remove the `D` function? Also, the spacing in `Show` was deliberate, it prevented the code from going off the screen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , thanks, i symplyficate the code and did it more readable, and formated it like Heike. Im sorry, as i sad, im not a specialist in this programm

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, (Ci^(0,1))[z,t] -  mean that it is a partial derivative function Ci for variable t. I dont know, i just read the help and selected one of the way of writing partial derivatives. Is usage funtion D is more preferable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, i reshare the file. Previous was Russians site, I dont know why it thry to download somthikn on you PC

Comment: @user does this code actually run fine on your machine if you cut and paste it?

Comment: @user no, this working code in attachment. In message i format it to more readable view. I try to fix it.

Comment: a) if you someone to be notified of your comments, try @username, eg, in my case, username=acl b) I will take a look at the attachment later today and try to help

Comment: @user1058051, `D` is preferable as the form `(Ci^(1,0))[z,t]` is just shorthand for `D[Ci[z,t], z]` and Mathematica (v.8) gives me an error when attempting to use the shorthand form. Internally, `D[Ci[z,t], z]` is represented as `Derivative[1,0][Ci][z,t]` which you could use, instead, but `D` requires less typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion the reason why it's failing on you is because you're caching the results.

Do you need to store every single solution that `NDSolve` is producing? I'm somewhat skeptical of whether this is useful or not for `Findfit`, since I highly doubt it would revisit a past result.

Besides, it's not like you're talking about integers where there's a finite domain you're talking about. You're using reals and even over the range you specify, there's *A LOT* of different solutions possible. I don't think you want to store each and every one of them.

Rewrite your code so that instead of having:

```
model[(De_)?NumberQ, (Kf_)?NumberQ, (Y_)?NumberQ] := 
 model[De, Kf, Y] =  yeld /. Last[Last[
     NDSolve[..]
```

You instead have:

```
model[(De_)?NumberQ, (Kf_)?NumberQ, (Y_)?NumberQ] := 
 NDSolve[..]
```

By caching your previous results, you're going to eat up memory like no tomorrow with `FindFit`. Typically it's useful when you have a recurrence relation, but here I'd seriously advise against it.

---

**Some Notes:**

After running for `2415` seconds on my machine, Mathematica's memory usage went from `112,475,400` bytes to `1,642,280,320` bytes with the caching.

I'm currently running the code without the caching now.

Comment: that is a good point. in any case, what you suggest is to suffer potentially slower performance for lower memory consumption. I admit I have not yet played with this problem though.

Comment: @acl: I'm still not convinced that memoizing the results of `NDSolve` would even help performance. I'm trying to run his code on my machine with and without the memoization, but it seems to be slow either way. Will post cpu time and memory usage once both runs finish.

Comment: I agree, in this case it looks like memoizing won't help speed, for the reasons you outlined. I tried running this some time ago but cut and pasting the code didn't work, and I have had no time to revisit it to see if the edits make it runnable.

Comment: @acl: The question has the code from the uploaded notebook, along with some minor syntactical changes on my part. It should run fine.